# Let the only one button can be select in three buttons and if I click again it can go back original state

Tags: java, android

There are three buttons in my Fragment.I would like to let my user select only one button.if one of theme is selected, others can't be selected.And other buttons can't change it's look , not like setEnabled() just normal like default,if user clicks again the button can go back original state.

Here's my code.

```
private Button.OnClickListener firstRow = new Button.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            switch (v.getId()) {


                case R.id.btnFirst:
                btnfirst.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FEF3C5"));
                break;


                case R.id.btnSecond:
                    btnSecond.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FEF3C5"));
                    break;


                case R.id.btnThird:
                   btnThird.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FEF3C5"));
                        break;
                    }

                }

            };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your code with this code,

```
Button btnFirst,btnSecond,btnThird;
int counter = 0;

private Button.OnClickListener firstRow = new Button.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            counter += 1;
            if(counter<2){
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.btnFirst:
                    btnfirst.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FEF3C5"));
                    btnSecond.setClickable(false);
                    btnThird.setClickable(false);
                    break;


                case R.id.btnSecond:
                    btnSecond.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FEF3C5"));
                    btnFirst.setClickable(false);
                    btnThird.setClickable(false);
                    break;


                case R.id.btnThird:
                    btnThird.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FEF3C5"));
                    btnFirst.setClickable(false);
                    btnSecond.setClickable(false);
                    break;
            }
        }
        else {
//Cnage button backgrounds ad per te need to eac buttons
                counter = 0;
                btnFirst.setClickable(true);
                btnSecond.setClickable(true);
                btnThird.setClickable(true);
            }

        }

    };
```

Tis will work as per your need.Thank you

Edit: After question update(I am not deleting the previous answer for you need it in future)

Edit your code with this,

```
 Button btnFirst,btnSecond,btnThird;

   private Button.OnClickListener firstRow = new Button.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.btnFirst:
                    btnFirst.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FEF3C5"));
                    //Change btnFirst,btnThird backgrounds as default background
                    break;


                case R.id.btnSecond:
                    btnSecond.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FEF3C5"));
                    //Change btnFirst,btnThird backgrounds as default background
                    break;


                case R.id.btnThird:
                    btnThird.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FEF3C5"));
                    //Change btnFirst,btnSecond backgrounds as default background for example given below
                    btnFirst.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#defaultColor"));
                    btnSecond.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#defaultColor"));
                    break;
            }

        }

    };
```

Comment: Thanks for your helps. it's really close my need.but Maybe I didn't  say clearly.I still need others buttons can be selected , like there are three buttons user can choose any one , and they can change their mind, but just only one can choose, Example there are three kinds of drink you can buy, and you have to choose one not two, and if you change your mind you can still press others button.

Comment: @Kelvin let me know if now you have got your answer as per your need?

Comment: This is the same which I posted..... It can cause every button you can press and you can't re-choose.

Comment: No no.In this case you can rechoose the buttons but whenever you choose one button others will be set to default abckground.See the edited code there I have given an example.

Comment: As per your example " Example there are three kinds of drink you can buy, and you have to choose one not two, and if you change your mind you can still press others button." you have wanted to rechoose other buttons

Comment: @kevin I will wait for your comment if you have got your answer or not.I will post more code if you need

Comment: Pleasure is mine...Happy to see that you have got the solution...Thank you for your comment :)